# Given $X = (C[0,1], d_\infty)$ and $f_n \in X$ then for every $K \subseteq X$ compact, $f_n \nsubseteq K$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, sequence-of-function

Given $X = (C[0,1], d_\infty)$ and $f_n \in X$. I want to show that for every compact set $K \subseteq X$, $\{f_n : n \geq 1\} \nsubseteq K$.

Where
$f_n(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       0, &\quad 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n+1} \\
       \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n+1/2} - \frac{1}{n+1}}\cdot (x-\frac{1}{n+1}), &\quad \frac{1}{n+1} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n+1/2} \\
       \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n+1/2}-1/n}\cdot(x-1/n), &\quad \frac{1}{n+1/2} \leq x \leq 1/n\\
       0, &\quad 1/n \leq x \leq 1 \\ 
     \end{cases}
$

I am having a hard time proving this, since I haven't seen any exercises alike. I thought maybe I could use the fact that if $K$ is compact and $f_n(x) \subseteq K$ then it must have a convergent subsequence. Would the idea be then to show that the sequence of functions $f_n$ has no convergent subsequence in $C([0,1], d_\infty)$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right! More precisely, if a subsequence somehow had a limit, what would that limit look like and why could it not actually converge to it?

Comment: @Spintoo I think that if a subsequence had a limit it would be a function that is non-continuous, is that right?

Comment: Maybe, but also note that if it did converge in $X$'s topology, it would also converge pointwise, so you could try looking at its pointwise limit first. It might also be useful to draw what $f_n$ looks like if you haven't already, the formula makes it look more complicated than it really is.

Comment: Sure, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Spintoo If I am not wrong, $f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$. But the convergence isn't uniform.

Comment: Bingo! So that contradicts the convergence in $d_\infty$.

Comment: @Spintoo Why does what Rahid pointed out contradict the convergence of any subsequence?

Comment: @SaimFaigol Any convergent subsequence would have to converge pointwise to $0$, yet the $d_\infty$ distance between $0$ and $f_n$ is always equal to $1$, so it can't actually converge to it.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the clarification.